# Find a substring and evaluate an expression

Tags: java, arrays, indexof

I'm working on something that is probably java basics but I still do not understand even after reading some documentation.

I have a csv file that i read into a sTokens variable row by row. At each row I need to check the value in element [0] and compare it with what I need to be there.

I've an array of strings like this:

```
String [] sTokens = {"elem1", "elem2"};
```

The following does not work as expected:

```
if (sTokens[0].indexOf("texttofind".toLowerCase())>=10) {
   //do something
}
```

My expectation would be to have the evaluated expression return a number (in this case 10 or in worst case -1) and then do something based on the number returned e.g. 10 means I found what I needed.

I'm using the debug tool in Netbeans and when I evaluate the expression in parenthesis it returns 10 (like it is supposed to do).

Unfortunately, and here is probably my mistake, the expression is evaluated as NULL.

Any help would be very appreciated
lorenz

Comment: What the number is supposed to mean ? Because java.lang.String.contains() return a boolean true or false only.

Comment: @robinvrd sorry you are right!! I meant indexOf

Comment: what‘s content in your csv file

Comment: Your question says *"find a sub-string"*, but you're using indexOf? Are you looking for `.equals()`?

Comment: I thought equals work only for full matches, in this case I have a partial match. Let's say original string is text-xxx-elem1 I need to find elem1 within the string.

Comment: Try `.contains()` then..

Answer (score 1):

You are using indexOf wrongly. If this is what you have:

```
String [] sTokens = {"elem1", "elem2"};
```

And you run your code like this:

```
System.out.println(sTokens[0].indexOf("el".toLowerCase()));
```

It will print 0, because in sTokens[0] contains "el" starting at index 0.

If you run this:

```
System.out.println(sTokens[0].indexOf("em".toLowerCase()));
```

It will print 2, because "em" starts at index 2.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the sTokens might be in uppercase.Try doing this

```
String[] sTokens = {"Hello","TestC"};
if(sTokens [0].toLowerCase().indexOf("llo")>=2){
     //do something
}
```